# Merge two data frames with cell mismatches

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, gsub, grepl

I am currently stuck: I have webscraped a website which assigns very different names to the same product (i.e. the same product could be listed as "1", "Number 1", "Category 3 - Number 1"). To each of these values, I want to assign a different outcome (scraped from a different site with nicer names).

```
# Messy code from original website:
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4), c("Number 1", "Number 2", 
                                                      "Category 1", "3", "8",
                                                      "Number 2 - Category 5","1", "Number 4", 
                                                      "Kat 1", "4", "Kat 2", 
                                                      "Number5", "Test", "4","3"))
colnames(df1) <- c("ID", "Category")

> df1
   ID              Category
1   1              Number 1
2   1              Number 2
3   1            Category 1
4   1                     3
5   2                     8
6   2 Number 2 - Category 5
7   2                     1
8   3              Number 4
9   3                 Kat 1
10  3                     4
11  3                 Kat 2
12  3               Number5
13  4                  Test
14  4                     4
15  4                     3

# Code from other site:
df2 <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), c("1", "2", "3", "Category 1",
                                                      "Category 5", "1", "2", "3", "4",
                                                      "Kat 1", "Kat 2", "Kat 3","5",
                                                      "1","2","3","4","Test"), 
                  c(1,2,3,4,5,6,5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18))
colnames(df2) <- c("ID", "Category", "Outcome")

> df2
   ID   Category Outcome
1   1          1       1
2   1          2       2
3   1          3       3
4   1 Category 1       4
5   2 Category 5       5
6   2          1       6
7   2          2       5
8   2          3       8
9   3          4       9
10  3      Kat 1      10
11  3      Kat 2      11
12  3      Kat 3      12
13  3          5      13
14  4          1      14
15  4          2      15
16  4          3      16
17  4          4      17
18  4       Test      18
```

I want to keep data frame 1, but assign the "Output" taken from df2, matched by ID and Category. This could be easily accomplished with a left join, but as you can see, the category levels are not the same.

I have been thinking of renaming the levels, but given the size of my dataset (~500,000 rows), this does not seem to be feasible and I am hoping for a simpler (grepl, gsub?) solution.

My final result should look like this:

```
> df1
   ID              Category Outcome
1   1              Number 1       1
2   1              Number 2       2
3   1            Category 1       4
4   1                     3       3
5   2                     8      NA
6   2 Number 2 - Category 5       5
7   2                     1       6
8   3              Number 4       9
9   3                 Kat 1      10
10  3                     4       9
11  3                 Kat 2      11
12  3               Number5      13
13  4                  Test      18
14  4                     4      17
15  4                     3      16
```

Sorry for the complicated example, I wanted to make sure to cover all contingencies. Here a little more explanation:

Whenever it will have a category, this will usually be listed in full and in the correct spelling (i.e. "Kat" will always occur as "Kat" and "Category" will always occur as "Category"). Numbers may occur with the word "Number" in front or simply as the digit itself. If a number does not occur, I would like it to display NA - I will have to add the missing numbers by hand later.

Thank you so much for reading - I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: There are too many cases to handle I think but you can start by removing "Number" `df1$Category <- sub("Number ", "", df1$Category)` and then do left join `merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can likely be greatly simplified, but you could try:

```
library(dplyr)

extr_last_digit <- function(x) substring(x, first = regexpr("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)", x, perl = T))
extr_cat_digit <- function(x) gsub(".*((?<=Category\\s)\\d+).*|.*((?<=Kat\\s)\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", x, perl = T)

df1 %>%
  mutate(
    join = case_when(
      !grepl("Category|Kat", Category) ~ extr_last_digit(Category),
      TRUE ~ paste0("Category ", extr_cat_digit(Category)))
  ) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
              mutate(
                join = case_when(
                  !grepl("Category|Kat", Category) ~ extr_last_digit(Category),
                  TRUE ~ paste0("Category ", extr_cat_digit(Category))
                ),
                Category = NULL), 
            by = c("ID", "join")
  ) %>%
  select(-join)
```

Output:

```
   ID              Category Outcome
1   1              Number 1       1
2   1              Number 2       2
3   1            Category 1       4
4   1                     3       3
5   2                     8      NA
6   2 Number 2 - Category 5       5
7   2                     1       6
8   3              Number 4       9
9   3                 Kat 1      10
10  3                     4       9
11  3                 Kat 2      11
12  3               Number5      13
13  4                  Test      18
14  4                     4      17
15  4                     3      16
```

Basically what this does is it creates a `join` column in both `df` which has the same structure - if it doesn't find any mention of `Category` or `Kat`, it uses the last mentioned digit for merge, otherwise it pastes the word `Category` and the digit mentioned after either the word `Category` or `Kat`.

This also works with the word `Test` since if it doesn't find any digit it just uses the whole string.